# jQuery add class based on parent URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my homepage, I currently have a jQuery that adds a class (in this case an underline) to the link element. This works great and is based on comparing the url (url/firstsubmenu) in the browser with the href of the link element.

However as soon as I go to a child of that link element (url/firstsubmenu/secondsubmenu), the class is gone. I have tried to split the url so that the jQuery always looks for the parent but I just can't solve it. Can you help me?

Could it be solved by adding another code, like maybe "if (this).children().length > 0 ?"

Here is my jQuery:

```
var cururl = window.location.href;
cururl = cururl.split('#')[0];
jQuery("a.rs-layer").each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).attr('href')=== cururl){
        jQuery(this).addClass("current-slider-menu");
    }
});
```

EDIT: I am new to this, and I have tried so many different codes, googled for hours. I now know that I can only write JavaScript in my CMS. That is, I cannot use jQuery operators such as, for example, $.

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: Read up on `console.log()` and `console.dir()` for help debugging.

Comment: `cururl.split('/')[0];` or, more likely, `cururl.split("/").splice(1,3).join("/")`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately no success when trying them

Comment: try now its working for sub links  : workshop, field trips links 

Comment: I see. Now, I used your edited code, that was right?

Comment: I need the parent to be underlined... And only one of the submenus. Like if you go to works and click the first image, I need works to be still underlined... which it isn't unfortunately. But I guess your code can be modified very easily to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this instead, skipping the whole idea with text-decoration. 
I added an arrow. Finished.

JS:

```
var url = window.location.href;
  var msg = document.getElementById('current-menu-item-arrow');
  if( url.search( 'my-word' ) > 0 ) {
      msg.style.display = "block";
  }
```

CSS:

```
#current-menu-item-arrow {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

try   this

```
  var cururl = window.location.href;
    jQuery("rs-layer[id|='"+cururl.split('/')[3]+"'] , .rs-layer[href='"+cururl+"']").each(function(){
           jQuery(this).addClass("current-slider-menu");
    });
```

Comment: check again my answer  , i tested on your website    the  current  page   has underline

Comment: yes in the first level root/child but not in the second level root/child/child

Comment: So now I tried your edited code. However, I need the parent to be underlined... And only one of the submenus. Like if you go to works and click the first image, I need works (in the menu) to be still underlined... which it isn't unfortunately. But I guess your code can be modified very easily to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**,

Change the class/selectors as per your requirement. This will add a unique class in the li element, now you can style this using css.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_menu li").removeClass('current-slider-menu');
  $(".main_menu li>a").filter(function(){
    return  this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
  }).parent("li").addClass("current-slider-menu");
});
```

Comment: This will work for sure. Any clarification kindly share.

Comment: this disables the whole body, where I have sliders made with Slider Revolution.

Comment: Did you change the class??

Comment: I meant instead of writing .main_menu li>a, you need to write your own classes. Did you do that?

Comment: yes I did. The thing is that either the whole body or the menu itself gets disableb when using your code. I am writing this into revolution slider. There must be some markup in the code that the revolution slider system doesn't understand. Because your solution makes perfect sense!  Thanks so much by the way! Would I be so lucky that you would have a solution for what I descbribe?

Comment: also: do you think ".rs-layer" is the right class to add? (you see that I use it in my original code above). I also tried with giving all the menu items a new class.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track.

You can grab the `currentURL` (before the anchor `#`):

```
const currentURL = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
```

Then you can split the `currentURL` into its constituent folders:

```
const currentURLArray = currentURL.split('/');
```

Then, separately, you can grab all the `myLinks`:

```
const myLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.rs-layer')];
```

And finally you can cycle through `myLinks` and if the name of the folder you want to match does match the name of the equivalent folder in the `currentURL`, then you can add the `.current-slider-menu` class:

```
for (myLink of myLinks) {

  if (myLink.href.split('/')[1] === currentURLArray[1]) {

    myLink.classList.add('current-slider-menu');
  }
}
```

---

**Complete Example:**

```
const currentURL = window.location.href.split('#')[0];

const currentURLArray = currentURL.split('/');

const myLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.rs-layer')];

for (myLink of myLinks) {

  if (myLink.href.split('/')[1] === currentURLArray[1]) {

    myLink.classList.add('current-slider-menu');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, it underlines (adds the class) to all my links

Comment: You need to decide _which foldername_ you want to match against. In the example I have given above, I have matched against `[1]`, but you might want to match against a folder further along the URL path - ie. `[2]` or `[3]`.

Comment: I am not sure... I understand, this adds a class to an item that is active? Usually, this is called current-menu-item in most CMS but not in my case...

Comment: Before adding the class, you need to check to see if part of the current URL matches with the corresponding part of the link. You only want to actually add the class to the link if it matches. So the important consideration here, is what would you like to match. If we use _this page's URL_ as an analogy, you can match against `questions` (between the first `/` and the second `/`) - but that will match every question on Stack Overflow. Or you can match against `60259251` (between the second `/` and the third `/`) - which will match against this page's URL alone.

Comment: in my case "questions" is unique. I want to match against "questions" and "60259251"

Comment: So then your (multiple) condition will look something like this: `if ((myLink.href.split('/')[1] === currentURLArray[1]) && (myLink.href.split('/')[2] === currentURLArray[2]))'`.

Comment: thanks, that indeed loks good but when implementing it, my burger-menu is gone compeletely...

Comment: Please state why you think that might be.

Comment: I have no idea. Unfortunately.